# What are the correct SAPI input parameters to the succesfully usage?

Tags: c#

I have a problem this COM function I can't know what the correct parameters are.
I get bad notification from VS 2013.
Program: speakBoard

```
        WAVEFORMATEX waveFORMATEX = new WAVEFORMATEX();
        waveFORMATEX.wFormatTag = 1;
        waveFORMATEX.nChannels = 1;
        waveFORMATEX.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
        waveFORMATEX.wBitsPerSample = 16;
        waveFORMATEX.nBlockAlign = 4;
        waveFORMATEX.cbSize = 0;        

        SPVTEXTFRAG SPVtextFRAG = new SPVTEXTFRAG();
        SPVtextFRAG.pTextStart = "one";
        SPVtextFRAG.ulTextLen = 100;
        SPVtextFRAG.ulTextSrcOffset = 0;



        SpeakBoard1.STTTSEngine se;
        Guid rguid = new Guid("ggg");
        SpeakBoard1.ISpTTSEngineSite es;
        se.Speak(255, ref rguid, ref waveFORMATEX, ref SPVtextFRAG, es);
```

Comment: Here is the picture about...
http://postimg.org/image/yndqax4b7/

Comment: There is no point in using SAPI directly, it is wrapped well by the System.Speech namespace.  Use the SpeechSynthesizer class if you want to talk.

Comment: It's weak to use.
I want to use a better program and it has COM inputs but I can't use it. :(

Comment: And on the msdn I saw things but they are for C++.

Comment: @SK94 - What do you mean when you say: `It's weak to use`?

Comment: I mean it's not the best it's simple and not HQ.

Answer (score -1):

I face with similar problem for C++. This is my code for filling the main structure:

```
SPVTEXTFRAG fillSPVTEXTFRAG(){

    SPVTEXTFRAG spvTextFrag;
    spvTextFrag.pNext = NULL;

    spvTextFrag.State.eAction = SPVA_Speak;
    spvTextFrag.State.LangID = 3;
    spvTextFrag.State.wReserved = 3;
    spvTextFrag.State.EmphAdj = 3;
    spvTextFrag.State.RateAdj = 3;
    spvTextFrag.State.Volume = 100;

    spvTextFrag.State.PitchAdj.MiddleAdj = 0;
    spvTextFrag.State.PitchAdj.RangeAdj = 0;

    spvTextFrag.State.SilenceMSecs = 0;
    //spvTextFrag.State.pPhoneIds = ;

    spvTextFrag.State.ePartOfSpeech = SPPS_Unknown;// SPPARTOFSPEECH.SPPS_Unknown; 

    spvTextFrag.State.Context.pCategory;
    spvTextFrag.State.Context.pBefore;
    spvTextFrag.State.Context.pAfter;

    spvTextFrag.pTextStart = L"one";
    spvTextFrag.ulTextLen = 100;
    spvTextFrag.ulTextSrcOffset = 0;

    return spvTextFrag;
}
```

This code fills one of five parameters for call the Speak method of ISpTTSEngine. But you also need to implement the ISpTTSEngineSite interface for such calls.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code for future reference? I don't really get if this actually solved the issue or if it's just a dump of your current state